# How do i get Javascript syntax (for parsing HH:MM:SS) into Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm pretty new to "coding" in Selenium and have recently installed Selenium IDE.

I'm trying to get my variable $WaitingTime, which is in "hh:mm:ss", to milliseconds in Selenium IDE.

I have found multiple solutions, I however have no idea how to translate these to Selenium commands en how store the result as a new variable.

one solution would be:

```
function hmsToSecondsOnly(str) {
var p = str.split(':'),
    s = 0, m = 1;

while (p.length > 0) {
    s += m * parseInt(p.pop(), 10);
    m *= 60;
}

return s;
}
```

How would these translate into Selenium IDE commands?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it that I've encountered before would be to utilise the user-extensions.js file. If you don't have this you can create it easily enough as a blank js file. Then you need to set it in selenium IDE (Options > options and there should be a field title Selenium Core Extensions, just set your file here)

You can then put your function above in that file and call it from selenium using storeEval

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>hmsToSecondsOnly("10:10:10")</td>
    <td>waitingTime</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${waitingTime}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

which prints the following in the console:

```
[info] Executing: |echo | ${waitingTime} | |
[info] echo: 36610
```

I'm assuming from the function name that this is meant to be in seconds, not milliseconds as you stated in your question. If it is milliseconds you need, you'd need to tweak your function to do that, but the same selenium functionality would apply.

Answer (score 0):

To easily manage all your javascript dates and times in Selenium you can use moment.js .. Install it and add it into Selenium as an extension.